# Should I no-index pages that are links to articles with a short blurb -- more than 90% of the posts on my blog

Tags: seo, google, google-search, noindex

I have created a site like Digg.com, Bizsugar.biz: managewp.org. My site niche is WordPress and Web Development.

Users can submit links to my site. So, many pages are low quality because it has only about 50 words and those are also copied from original article.  Eg. https://managewp.org/articles/13556/licensing-pros-and-cons-of-100-gpl-and-why-we-made-a-switch

I know that these pages are rally low quality and I can’t get SEO traffic.  I have added a blog to my site and I write 1000+ word quality post per week.  My traget is get SEO traffic for those blog posts.

Should I index only my blog and not the posts with the links? Should I no-index all low posts submitted by users of my site?

Note: This is not a duplicate question for [Should i noindex low/quality duplicate content tag pages?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86082/should-i-noindex-low-quality-duplicate-content-tag-pages)

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely add either a noindex tag or a canonical tag back to the original article pages as this is essentially content syndication.